# Scala package references

Tags: scala

In [section 9.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/09-top-level-definitions.html#package-references), the Scala spec says:

```
package b { 
  class B
}

package a.b {
  class A {
    val x = new _root_.b.B
  }
}
```

> Here, the reference *root*.b.B refers to class B in the toplevel
>   package b. If the *root* prefix had been omitted, the name b would
>   instead resolve to the package a.b, and, provided that package does
>   not also contain a class B, a compiler-time error would result.

However, it compiles and the package reference **b.B** seems to be absolute and
not relative one.

Comment: What's the question? At a glance this looks like it might be a bug in the spec, but this isn't really the place to report that.

Comment: It was exactly my question, whether it is a bug or I misunderstand the spec.